# URL rewriting reserved names

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

In my .htaccess file I have the following rewrite rule:

`RewriteRule ^user/(.*) user.php?username=$1 [NC,L]`

to take `domain.com/user/anything` and rewrite it to be used in my application.

However, I want to rewrite it to

`domain.com/anything`.

The only issue is, there are reserved file names that shouldn't be usernames when accessed, such as `index` (`domain.com/index`). What if the user has the name `index`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following rule to exclude existent dirs and files from the rule :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*) user.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
```

If you want to exclude specific uris from the rule, you could use the following instead :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!index|upload|foo|bar).+) user.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: but now when I access `domain.com/upload` it tries to look for the user 'upload', instead of going to the upload page.

Comment: Would I need to do something like this `RewriteRule ^(?!index$|upload|etc$)(.*) user.php?username=$1 [NC,L]` and disallow users from having those specific names?